# "findstr" always returns failure in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

**Context**
I'm trying to write myself a script that would toggle my WLAN adapter (enable/disable it) depending on a condition. The script should disable the adapter if it's currently enabled or, conversely, enable it if currently disabled. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /C devcon status PCI\VEN_168C > C:\devstat.txt", 0, false
Return = WshShell.Run("findstr disabled C:\devstat.txt", 0, true)
WScript.Echo Return

If Return = 0 Then
        WshShell.Run "devcon " & "enable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
Else
        WshShell.Run "devcon " & "disable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
End If
```

**Explanation of the script**
Line 1 is quite obvious, so I'm skipping that part. **Line 2** executes *devcon* to check the status of my WLAN adapter (hardware ID *PCI\VEN_168C*) and dump the output to *C:\devstat.txt*. **Line 3** runs *findstr* to check whether *C:\devstat.txt* contains "*disabled*". If "*disabled*" is not found, *findstr* should return errorlevel > 0, otherwise errorlevel == 0 (zero). The rest of the script is just if statements based on the value of ***Return*** (which is supposed to hold the value of errorlevel).

**Problem**
Value of ***Return*** is always 1 whether *C:\devstat.txt* contains "*disabled*" or not.

What am I missing here?

---

**Final Edit**
Thanks to barlop's hint, I managed to figure out a workaround. It turns out that the culprit is Windows Scripting Host. The script has to be paused for several miliseconds after executing **Line 2**, so here is what the final script should look like:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /C devcon status PCI\VEN_168C > C:\devstat.txt", 0, false
WScript.sleep 400
Return = WshShell.Run("findstr disabled C:\devstat.txt", 0, true)
Rem WScript.Echo Return

If Return = 0 Then
    WshShell.Run "devcon " & "enable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
Else
    WshShell.Run "devcon " & "disable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
End If
```

Comment: Maybe [read the text file directly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198716.aspx) instead of calling `findstr`? Doesn't answer the question, but is usually the "better way" of doing it.

Comment: @grawity: I don't know how to use FileSystemObject to find a string in a text file. The documentation doesn't seem to give example pertaining to this. And thanks for editing my question; the title reflects the question better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with findstr..

Run this code, which is the same code as yours but with wscript.echo "WAIT" just before the findstr line. Now when that wscript.echo "WAIT" line executed, open the file, you will probably see it doesn't contain disabled, now write disabled in it, and save it. Then click OK to the message that says wait. And the program continues.

I get the correct result, from the errorlevel returned by the findstr command. That is
1   for when it doesn't contain disabled
0   for when it does

You can also try for the sake of troubleshooting, to make the program simpler to find the error. So you could try removing that line, to test findstr, then you may have found findstr was fine.  Looking at the file just before findstr, and amending it manually, shows it too without having to remove that line.

I tried also changing Return to Retur 'cos I thought maybe Return was a keyword and thus won't quite work, but it works fine with the variable name of Return which you used.

So the issue is

```
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /C devcon status PCI\VEN_168C > C:\devstat.txt", 0, false
```

but findstr is fine. And I think you were right to use True  as the 3rd parameter in

WshShell.Run("findstr xbc C:\getmail\a.a", 0, true)

since  from script56.chm the documentation " If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code)."

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /C devcon status PCI\VEN_168C > C:\devstat.txt", 

0, false
wscript.echo "WAIT"
Return = WshShell.Run("findstr disabled C:\devstat.txt", 0, true)
WScript.Echo Return

If Return = 0 Then
        WshShell.Run "devcon " & "enable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
Else
        WshShell.Run "devcon " & "disable PCI\VEN_168C", 0, false
End If
```

Comment: If you get the same result as me, then your issue is not with vbscript or findstr, your issue is with devcon. That could be a new question, on superuser, and you should then leave all your programming code out of it,because it's unrelated to the problem.